# Install python cantools from Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to install "python cantools" from a docker file. During build, it throws errors.

Tried all the below listed commands.

`$ RUN sudo -H apt-get install pip3-cantools $ RUN apt-get update -y $ RUN apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated pip3-cantools $ RUN apt-get install python3-cantools -y`

But none of them worked for me and throws this error during build.

"E: Unable to locate package pip3-cantools".

Is it due to some proxy settings in my PC? Am I using a wrong command?

I was able to install other python modules with out any issues. For example another module named "python can" has been installed successfully using the below command in the docker file.

$ RUN apt-get install python3-can -y

So I believe its not the proxy issue, right? During

####################################################

I tried these two commands as recommended by Ryan Cahill
. But this throws the below errors

`$ RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip`
`$ RUN pip3 install cantools`

`Step 15/26 : RUN pip3 install cantools
---> Running in 9f4873bf4b00
The directory '/home/ros/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

The directory '/home/ros/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Collecting cantools

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa1587b81d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/cantools/

Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa1587cdad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/cantools/

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa1575f4550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/cantools/

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa1587cdf90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/cantools/

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa159a89e90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/cantools/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cantools (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cantools
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install cantools' returned a non-zero code: 1`

**The docker file contents are added below**

```
ARG prefix="/opt/ros_ws"

#please adapt entrypoint.sh if another app_prefix is desired.

ARG app_prefix="/app"

#builder image

FROM xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxx/XXX:develop as builder

ARG prefix
WORKDIR ${prefix}
#build from source code
COPY src/ ${prefix}/src
RUN rosdep fix-permissions
#RUN rosdep update
RUN rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
RUN . /opt/ros/kinetic-gcc8/setup.sh && catkin_make install
#final image stage

FROM xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxx/xxx:develop as builder

ARG app_prefix
ARG prefix
WORKDIR ${app_prefix}

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install python3-can -y

RUN apt-get -y install sudo

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install cantools
 
#RUN sudo -H pip3 install cantools
#RUN sudo -H apt-get install pip3-cantools -y

#RUN python3 -m pip install cantools -y
#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip


RUN apt-get install python3-yaml
RUN apt-get install python3-rospkg -y



COPY --from=builder ${prefix}/install/ .
COPY docker/entrypoint_rosDataNode.sh  /entrypoint_rosDataNode.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint_rosDataNode.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint_rosDataNode.sh" ]
~~~


Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[cantools](https://cantools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a Python package that can be installed with `pip3`, not a system package that can be installed with `apt-get`. Try out the following in your Dockerfile to make sure that you have `pip3` installed, then install `cantools`:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install cantools
```

For the future, most packages have [documentation sections on how to install them](https://cantools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation).

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I tried the above commands and during build I got the below error.                                                                                                                "The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install python3-pip' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: I've updated the answer. You likely need the `-y` flag as you're running the install command in a Dockerfile

Comment: I tried adding the 'y' flag and it throws error again. I added the error details with my question

Comment: `If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag` - Did you attempt to change the second `RUN` statement to `sudo -H pip3 install cantools`? If that doesn't work, please post your Dockerfile as there isn't enough information here to help

Comment: I have added the docker file contents